# Use html to create autocomplete box for iphone browser

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, autocomplete

Creating some simple html pages specific for the iphone, and would like to use autocomplete for one of my textboxes. Is it possible to do this with javascript and if so, how?

Comment: You can pretty much just search for autocomplete on google and get a ton of results. Here is one plugin for the jQuery javascript library: [jQuery Autocomplete][1]


  [1]: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery offers many Autocompleters: http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html

edit: I did't see the comment. Do you want an Autocompleter which does only work with the iPhone / which is written especially for the iPhone?